# Sencha Touch- setting properties in Ext.create(

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch. Running through the examples on their site and getting unexpected behavior.. Could not figure out why.. Wondering if someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong..

Basically- defined a new Class.. Defined a property called 'name' set to null. Then created a new instance of the Animal class, and set 'name' : 'Bob'.. But it does not seem to ever get set..

Should I be able to set properties this way, when creating a new instance of the object? The tutorial seems to say I should.. Calling bob.setName('some name') does work, but I was hoping to be able to set the values in the create method..

The code:

```
Ext.define('Animal', {
        config: {
            name: null
        },

        speak: function() {
            alert(this.getName());
        }
    }); 

    var bob = Ext.create('Animal', {
        name: 'Bob' // set 'name' to Bob
    });

    bob.speak(); //alerts 'null' - site says it should alert 'Bob'
    alert( bob.getName() ); //alerts null
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with this code? You can always set properties this way. Whatever property you add in config, will automatically have  set/get methods for them.

Comment: Thanks for responding! hmm, okay, I thought so too, but it does not seem to set the name property for my * custom * class, though I can set properties in config for existing EWT classes.

Comment: Can you share your custom class code?

Comment: Thank you Swar! I am certain its something fundamental that I am doing wrong.. 
Here is my app.js code: 
<code>
    Ext.application({
  name: 'Sencha',

  launch: function() {
 
   Ext.define('Animal', { 
    config: { name: 'SOME DEFAULT NAME' },
        
    speak: function() {
      alert(this.getName());
    }
   }); 

   var bob = Ext.create('Animal', {
    name: "Bob's name" // set name property to "Bob's name"
    });
    
   // Both of these alerts display 'SOME DEFAULT NAME' ---> should alert "Bob's name"
   bob.speak(); 
   alert( bob.getName() );
        }
    });<code>

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, I could not get it to display like code :/ <FAIL> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I never defined a constructor that updated the config properties. I thought that happened auto-magically by the framework, but seems not to.

The problem code was in this block:

```
Ext.define('Animal', { 
   config: { name: null },

   speak: function() {
      alert(this.getName());
   }
});
```

Which was missing the setting of the config in the constructor:

```
Ext.define('Animal', { 
   config: { name: null },

   constructor: function(config) {
      this.initConfig(config);

      return this;
   },

   speak: function() {
      alert(this.getName());
   }
});
```

Now when I create the new Animal instance, the name is set

```
var bob = Ext.create('Animal', {
    name: 'Bob' // set 'name' to Bob
});

bob.speak(); //now alerts 'Bob'
alert( bob.getName() ); //alerts 'Bob'
```